# Filling a histogram in parallel using openMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I would like to fill a histogram in parallel using openMP given an array of floating point numbers. I have found two potential solutions.

First method:

```
void compute_histogram(float *numbers, int number_count, int *histogram, int number_bins) {
    int thread_count = omp_get_max_threads();
    #pragma omp parallel
        {   
            int local_histogram[thread_count][number_bins]; //Allocation of a local histogram to be added to the actual histogram, "histogram".
            int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
            #pragma omp for //uses the same number of threads that were created upon #pragma omp parallel (
            for (int x = 0; x < number_count; x++) {
                float read_num = numbers[x];
                local_histogram[tid][(int)(read_num / (biggest_number_in_float_array / number_bins))]++;
            } //implicit barrier that waits for all threads to complete before proceeding to next section of code.
            #pragma omp for //same number of threads used
            for (int x = 0; x < number_bins; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < thread_count; y++)
                    histogram[x] += local_histogram[y][x]; //adding to the actual histogram.
            }
}
```

The above method printed out numbers that were exponentially greater than the number of elements provided within the array. Maybe due to faulty allocation. Thus, the second method:

```
void compute_histogram(float *numbers, int number_count, int *histogram, int number_bins) {
    int thread_count = omp_get_max_threads();
    int** local_histogram = malloc(thread_count * number_bins * sizeof(int)); 
//this malloc call for a 2D array is declared outside the parallel section 
//and is thus local to all threads within this section 
//(unlike previous implementation where the array was declared within the parallel 
//section and thus maintains private scope).
    #pragma omp parallel
        {
            int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
            #pragma omp for
            for (int x = 0; x < number_count; x++) {
                float read_num = numbers[x];
                local_histogram[tid][(int)(read_num / ( biggest_number_in_array_of_floats / number_bins))]++;
            }
            #pragma omp for
            for (int x = 0; x < number_bins; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < thread_count; y++)
                    histogram[x] += local_histogram[y][x];
            }
}
```

This however results in a segmentation fault (core dumped).

Please inform me on any potential source of error. Thanks.

Comment: I rolled back the 'changes'.  They weren't changes at all but the replacement of one question with another.  If you don't like this question anymore delete it.  But don't change it so much that the answer(s) become irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code (e.g. `local_histogram` is uninitialized, number of threads in the current team was not correctly obtained,incorrect 2D array allocation, summing of `local_histogram` was not correct), but you do not need to do it manually, OpenMP can do it for you properly using reduction:

```
void compute_histogram(float *numbers, int number_count, int *histogram, int number_bins) {    
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:histogram[:number_bins])
    for (int x = 0; x < number_count; x++) {
        float read_num = numbers[x];
        histogram[(int)(read_num / (20.0 / number_bins))]++;
    }        
}
```

Comment: This does get rid of the segmentation fault, but the numbers that are getting added to histogram are still way out of scope (like within the millions range). Some are correct, but some are way off.

Comment: Most probably `histogram` is not initialized. The sum of `histogram` array should equal to `number_count`. If you cannot solve this issue, please send a [mre].

Comment: Thank you for the help, which was immense. I think I should be able to figure out how to fix my code given some time.

Comment: Add this line before `#pragma omp parallel` to clear the array: `memset(histogram, 0, number_bins*sizeof(*histogram));`